# Блок шириной 100% экрана посредине сайта?

Tags: html, вёрстка

Допустим, у меня есть сайт шириной 1000 пикселов. И в нем две колонки. Как сделать блок, который бы шел где-то после этих двух колонок шириной, 100% от экрана, а затем снова бы шли колонки???

Comment: Конкретнее пожалуйста.

Момент с 2мя колонками и шириной 100% экрана не ясен.

Comment: А весь экран у вас 146%?

Comment: Посредине имеется в виду в вертикальном потоке блоков.

Answer (score 1):

Для того блока, который в обёртке `1000px`, задать `position: absolute; width: 100%; position` - выдернет из потока ваш внутренний блок, а ширина будет растянута на весь экран для любого монитора (не забудьте указать `height` для блока), остаётся только через свойство `top:` подогнать отступ сверху.

Так как ширина будет 100%, то никакие отступы и пэйдинги слева и справа не нужны, а значит можно подогнать блок через отступ сверху (свойство `top:`), если надо конечно.

И про `z-index` не забываем, если я Вас правильно понял.

Comment: @Илья Знаменский, не указывайте top) 

    .c { position: absolute; left: 0px; width: 100%; }

Comment: А не легче этот блок обернуть в табличку и поставить valign: middle (ну вы меня поняли к чему я клоню ☺), и тогда он будет не только посередине горизонтали, а ещё и по вертикале.

Comment: @Миха Николаев - за такие подделки реально хочется сильно бить по рукам (молотком, и лучше несколько раз для профилактики).

Зачем городить костыль на ровном месте? Не все что "проще" - лучше

Comment: @AlexWindHope ты на меня не гони, а предложи свою идею как ты это видишь!! За одно и поржем!! пхаахахах

Comment: Мне верстка давным давно не интересна и отвечать на подобного рода вопросы тоже, @GenchiK уже дал адекватный ответ, то же что написал ты - бред.

"пхаахахах" в твоем комменте лишь подтверждает твою неадыкватность

Comment: @AlexWindHope все хватит, погаричились и все со с кем не бывает)) Мир??

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать свойство float. Делаешь как то так:

```
<div style="clear:both">
   <div style="width:50%; float:left"></div>
   <div style="width:50%; float:left"></div>
</div>
<div style="height:100px"></div>
<div style="clear:both">   
    <div style="width:50%; float:left"></div>   
    <div style="width:50%; float:left"></div>
</div>
```

но я бы лучше использовал bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Выбирай:

- `width: 100vw`
- `position: fixed`
- `position: absolute` при соответствующем контексте